# QUIERO HACER UN FILTRO DE BUSQUEDA CON GUION BAJO EN LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Hola Comunidad tengo este problema quiero filtrar un datatable pero en el filtro debe tener guion bajo ejemplo leche_tubo y debe filtrarme todas las leches y los tubos que existan en la grilla de antemano su agradecimiento

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Además de la lectura recomendada, lee [ask]: edita tu pregunta para que no parezca un ticket de desarrollo, y demuestra lo que has intentado. Y por cierto... Las mayúsculas sostenidas indican que estás GRITANDO :)

Answer (score -1):

Hola puedes usar Where y contains

```
List<string> productos = new List<string>() { "leche_tubo", "papas_tubo"};
var resultado = productos.Where(x => x.Contains("leche"));
```